# View SQL on Groovy script save

Tags: arrays, json, grails, groovy

I have a Controller that doesn't insert due to some error.  I want to see the SQL or even an error but the console in my SSTS IDE doesn't show either.  Is there a way for me to see the SQL it is creating and force it to spit out the error to console?  I have loggingSql = true in my Database.groovy config

```
class OrdersController {
    def save = {
        def input = request.JSON

        def order = new Orders(input)
        // I want to see the SQL output of this save
        order.save(flush:true)

    }   

}
```

Comment: Can you share your DataSource.groovy? Are you sure you are running in the environment where you defined `loggingSql = true`?

Comment: Yes I have all the different environments with loggingSQL=true, just to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you aren't getting to a stage where there is any SQL.  What's probably happening is that your `Orders` is not passing validation, and therefore fails before the database is even in play.

You should *never* have a simple `foo.save()` — it should always be

```
if(foo.save()) {
    // save successful
} else {
    // save failed
}
```

**or**

```
foo.save(failOnError: true)
```

(`flush: true` has no effect if the validation fails.)

The [documentation goes into further detail](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html), including examples of how to see which fields failed.

Comment: Cool I will give it a shot and let you know.